Can I do a normal straight line in ER diagram in Mermaid?
The lines between boxes in ER are... weird. Is there no support for just a normal line, without all the noise?
https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/entityRelationshipDiagram.html

You might have to be a bit more specific about what you mean by !Is there no support for just a normal line, without all the noise?" may be include a before and after?

@phuzi Compared with the tool d2, you can use -- for a straight line. I'd expect something like that in mermaid, but maybe they are (too?) committed to standards. :)

If you are looking for straight/right angle lines, you can change the diagram type declaration to flowchart-elk, instead of flowchart or graph.
This uses a different rendering engine that makes for slightly nicer looking diagrams.

Nice tip, will give it a go :)
